# Subversive deleted a file that was not marked for deletion

Tags: svn, subversive

subversive deleted a file that a needed really badly, i am looking for ways to retrieve it. here are the steps that i followed:

- refreshed my local project folder
- synchronized to my svn repository
- only changes found were local files
- i chose commit, but obtained a error that the file was already in the repository
- on that file, i did override and commit, then i obtained an error that negative revisions were not authorized. it then did not give me an option, deleted my local file and that was it.

is there any way that i can retrieve my local file? help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "i did override"? This description doesn't fit any SVN operation I know of. Commits either succeed or fail, there is no way to "override" a commit failure.

Comment: @wim: i have subversive installed on eclipse, in the synchronize view, there is an option for "override and commit"

Comment: It sounds like you've been ... subverted!

Comment: @Josh K: it was not actually SVN which caused this error. It was a combination of user error and a dangerous feature in the subversive eclipse plugin, and I have edited the question accordingly. Unless git has some way to prevent user errors (think `git reset --hard`) then switching version control system will not help.

Comment: @Wim: It was a bit of a joke, git will let you screw up harder and faster then subversion ever will. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your local file was not in the repository, and it has been deleted, I'm afraid it's beyond version-control and you'll have to try normal data recovery methods to get it back. It sounds like the equivalent of `rm`ing a file you did not back up.

Comment: rm ing a file? i unfortunately never play with command line stuff, no patience for it and not visual enough for me :)

Comment: but that was my thought, it simply has been deleted. since it was a model for an mvc-based framework, most of the functions are public and i can "simply" rewrite them all. just tedious and annoying. thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a clean checkout and then revert back to where the file was?

Comment: the file never made it to version control actually, it was new. that's why i dont get why it said that something about negative numbers in revisions.

Comment: @jansen: Ah, in that case you are best looking at file recovery software.

Answer (score 0):

Could you retrieve it from the recycle bin? or use some nice recovery tool to retrieve it?
What OS are you using?

Comment: i have tried looking into the recycle bin and into everything i (easily) can. i havent looked into recovery tool yet.